# Change text based on exact scroll percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, percentage

I'm trying to cycle through numbered questions based on the exact percentage of what what the user has scrolled. My goal is to get this to work responsively.

I've created a sample fiddle so that you see what I'm trying to do...

```js
$(document).ready(

$(window).scroll(function(){

var progress = $(this).scrollTop() / $(document).height();

//calculate the percentage of the total window that the user has scrolled

var questNum = progress * 4;

//multiply that by the total number of questions, to get the corresponding question number


if (questNum < 1) {
 $('#question').text('Hello?');
} 

else if (questNum < 2) {
 $('#question').text("It's me...");
} 

else if (questNum < 3) {
 $('#question').text('I was wondering if after all these years...');
} 

else if (questNum < 4) {
        $('#question').text('You'd like to meet.');
}
else{
        $('#question').text('*ring ring*');
};
});
);
```

```css
*{
  height: 500px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span id="question" style="position: fixed">...</span>
</div>
```

In theory it seems like it should work, but I'm so lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to correct or change:

1. `$(document).ready` needs a function as its argument, so add `function() { ... }`;
2. Single quotes need to be escaped with a backslash when they occur in a single-quoted string: `'It\'s me...'` and `'You\'d like to meet.'`
3. As you don't know on which window size your code will run, setting `500px` as window height will only have the desired effect on some devices. Instead, set the height dynamically:

   ```
   $('body').height($(document).height() + slackSpace);
   ```

   ... where *slackSpace* should be the number of pixels you want to have available for scrolling.
4. The space you leave for scrolling (*slackSpace*) should be greater when you have more questions, so it should be made dependent on the number of questions. You would need to decide how many pixels scrolling would need to be done before switching to the next question. You could therefore define *slackSpace* as follows:

   ```
   var slackSpace = 5 * scrollPerQuestion;
   ```

   ...where the `5` would be the number of questions. That number should better be managed dynamically (cf. next point).
5. It will be easier to manage if you put your questions in an array. You then don't need those `if .. else if ... else if ...`, but can just pick the question text by its number:

   ```
   var questions = [
       'Hello?',
       'It\'s me...',
       'I was wondering if after all these years...',
       'You\'d like to meet.',
       '*ring ring*'
   ];
   // ... once you have the questNum value:
   $('#question').text(questions[questNum]);
   ```

   This way you also have access to the number of questions: `questions.length`.
6. The calculation of the progress is not correct. The two parts measure a different aspect: the scroll top gives the *top* of the (visible) content, while the document height corresponds to the *bottom* offset of all content. The difference between the two will be at least the window height, so you'll  never get a progress of 100% like that. It will probably even make some questions unreachable. Instead use this:

   ```
   var progress = $(window).scrollTop() / slackSpace;
   ```

   ... where *slackSpace* is the value defined in the previous point.
7. Some browsers retain the previous scroll position when you come back to a page or refresh it. So you'll want to scroll the page to the top whenever the page loads.
8. The document has a default margin of some pixels at each side. This badly influences the calculation of the progress. To make things easier, set that margin to zero and apply some spacing to the question element itself so that the text still appears at a nice distance of the window borders (also give the question element a class name instead of an inline style):

   ```
   body {
       margin: 0px;
   }
   .question {
       position: fixed;
       padding: 10px;
   }
   ```

Here is the code applying all these ideas:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var questions = [
        'Hello?',
        'It\'s me...',
        'I was wondering if after all these years...',
        'You\'d like to meet.',
        '*ring ring*'
    ];

    // How many pixels to scroll before going to next question
    var scrollPerQuestion = 50;
    // Total space needed to scroll through all questions
    var slackSpace = questions.length * scrollPerQuestion;
    // Set appropriate document height for scrolling all questions:
    $('body').height($(document).height() + slackSpace);
    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        // Calculate the percentage of the total window that the user has scrolled
        var progress = $(window).scrollTop() / slackSpace;
        // Convert progress into question number
        var questNum = Math.floor(progress * questions.length);
        // Make sure the question number does not pass the maximum
        var questNum = Math.min(questNum, questions.length);
        // Display corresponding question
        $('#question').text(questions[questNum]);
    });
    // Scroll to top on page load
    $(window).scrollTop(0).trigger('scroll');
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0px;
}
.question {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="question" class="question">...</span>
</div>
```

... it will do the job in the snippet.

Comment: I am still deep into the JS/jQuery noob phase. You have no idea how much I appreciate not only fixing the code, but also exposing flaws in my logic. I actually get to learn better habits from this code as opposed to just copying it and not understanding why it works. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code on

> $(document).ready(function(){

and

> $('#question').text('You\'d like to meet.');

Try this instead. It should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //$(document).ready(

$(window).scroll(function(){

var progress = $(this).scrollTop() / $(document).height();

//calculate the percentage of the total window that the user has scrolled

var questNum = progress * 4;

//multiply that by the total number of questions, to get the corresponding question number


if (questNum < 1) {
    $('#question').text('Hello?');
} 

else if (questNum < 2) {
    $('#question').text("It's me...");
} 

else if (questNum < 3) {
    $('#question').text('I was wondering if after all these years...');
} 

else if (questNum < 4) {
        $('#question').text('You\'d like to meet.');// $('#question').text('You'd like to meet.');
}
else{
        $('#question').text('*ring ring*');
}
});
});//);
```